# Newest kernel 3.13.0-33 causes boot problems

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I just installed the newest kernel *3.13.0-33* and after a reboot the computer won't boot further than the plymouth screen. Normally, the mouse cursor would apear and my second monitor would show that it has a signal, but neither happened with the new kernel.

I managed to select the last kernel version *3.13.0-32* in grub so I could boot again.
Is there a way to remove the newly installed kernel or to select *3.13.0-32* as the default one so I don't have to select it everytime I boot? Do you have an idea why it doesn't work?

---

### Specs

ASRock B75 Pro3-M
Intel® Core™ i5-3570K CPU @ 3.40GHz × 4
GeForce GTX 660/PCIe/SSE2
16 GB RAM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Terminal and Type :- `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` After this It will show all linux kernels installed in your system.

Now type :- `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x.x-generic` Replace **x.x.x**.- With the kernel you want to remove

eg:-

```
 sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-33-generic
```

After Deleting kernel Type :- `sudo update-grub` and reboot

Comment: The `update-grub` part was the one I was missing. Thank you!

Comment: @jnuk  if you have dual boot  update woes you have GRUB installed

Answer (score 1):

try

> sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-33-generic

to remove newly installed kernel.

Comment: Is it safe to remove all of the following packages? `linux-generic* linux-image-3.13.0-33-generic*
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-33-generic* linux-image-generic*`

Comment: yes but update the kernel on your device first , then remove old version

Comment: you can check the old version of kernels by 
`dpkg -l | grep linux-image`

Comment: @HanyAlsamman I don't want to remove the older versions, but the newest one. And `linux-generic linux-image-generic` seem pretty important to me... Are you sure it's safe to remove them?

Comment: While you can go into Synaptic, search for all the bits and pieces of previous kernels, and mark them for removal, here is a much easier method

Comment: removing `linux-header-3.13.0-33`, `linux-header-3.13.0-33-generic` and `linux-image-3.13.0-33-generic` will do the work.